# Is it true that $\varinjlim A_n^{**}=(\varinjlim A_n)^{**}$?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $(A_n, \phi_n)$ be an inductive system of $C^*$ algebras. It's well known double dual of $C^*$-algebra is again a $C^*$ algebra.

> Is it true that $\varinjlim A_n^{**}=(\varinjlim A_n)^{**}$

Can someone give me any reference?

Comment: No. Almost never. Think about AF algebras.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA: Thank you. But ig same  result is true in category of operator spaces?

Comment: The answer to your new question is still no, and I claim that if you think about how @NarutakaOZAWA's example/hint works, you should see how to adapt it

Comment: If both inductive limits (*i.e.* colimits) are interpreted in the category of C$^*$-algebras, the answer is no, as already mentioned. However, if the colimit $\varinjlim A_n^{**}$ is interpreted in the category of W$^*$-algebras (with normal *-homomorphisms) the answer is yes because $({-})^{**}$ is the left adjoint to the forgetful functor from W$^*$-algebras to C$^*$-algebras.